# Code blocks do not show completely in Android 5 mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app, code-block

Very long code blocks get truncated, this is a problem for CodeReview where long code blocks are common. The problem was not seen on Android 4.

[Example question were the bug is seen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134065/todo-remove-duplication-in-xml-parsing)

[image: Screenshot with truncated code]

Brand: Vodafone

Model: Smart Prime 6

Android Version: 5.0.2

Comment: @rene screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxW2x7KJABOAeVN3b2JzYU5EUHM/view?usp=docslist_api.  Thr trouble is that the code stops suddenly and the block goes blank.

Comment: thanks for the report! I'm trying to reproduce this on my test devices and will report back if I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: [I'm having the same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308822/156206) on Android 7.

Comment: Same here on a Moto G5 with Android 7.0; I can only see the first 91 lines of a code block.

Comment: The iOS app has a similar problem, which I reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321395/323179). The issues are probably only a coincidence though.