# Incomplete rendering of code blocks in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, code, code-block

I'm running the Stack Exchange app v1.0.95 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running Android v7.0.

Over the last few days, I'm noticing that the app doesn't fully render code blocks anymore. It renders only the first ~65 lines of code, then the rest of the block is blank, even though space has been set aside for the full code.

However, this only happens when viewing a question. Previewing a question that is being edited renders the full code.

Does anyone else see this?

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281041/323179) the same problem?

Comment: This just randomly started happening to me on the Android app about a couple months ago. I can't remember if it coincided with me getting a Note 8 or not. It only renders the first bit. You can load the rest if you click the code though.

Comment: @Laurel looks like it is the same problem, yes

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, I didn't think to click on the code. That does indeed render the full code.