# Expanded code block not showing all the code sometimes in app

Tags: bug, ios-app, code-block

Sometimes, tapping on a code block to expand it works good, as it does here (different scrolls shown):

[image]

[image]

[2018: a year in spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321346/323179)

In the above I am able to zoom and pan around.

And sometimes it doesn’t work. 
This is what a different code block looks like scrolled all the way to the right:

[image]

And this is how far down it goes:

[image]

It is supposed to go further in both directions. It is also very zoomed in, and you can’t zoom in or out. I think this happens when the block is above a certain dimension. See the full thing here: [2018: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321318/323179)

I’m also seeing this with real code, such as here: [print a binary tree vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54010605/6083675) (random example).

In one case a code block expanded properly the first time then bugged every other time. Here is a screenshot of it working properly with [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79118/104611) (although it’s zoomed out I can pinch to zoom in):

[image]

This could end badly. If it’s not obvious that a code block is cut off, who knows what the actual code will do. But I see it likely wasting someone’s time, since if you see code that apparently doesn’t work or is incomplete you’re likely to leave a very confusing comment.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)